# Active Directory Recycle Bin on child domain only

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2

We got a root domain *contoso.com* which contains some child domains like *sitea.contoso.com*, *siteb.contoso.com*. etc.
I'd like to enable the Active Directory Recycle Bin on one of these child domains and only there. The root and all domain functional levels are 2008R2. Each domain including the root domain has its own set of domain controllers managed individually.
I'm reading through some docs now, unfortunately most of them are talking about single domain forests.
From my understanding, the recycle bin feature has to be enabled on the root domain *contoso.com* and can not be activated on child domains. But after activating each child domain has its own recycle bin.
Is this correct?

Is it possible to activate the recycle bin feature on say *sitec.contoso.com* without touching the root domain?

I'm asking because each domain is managed independently by different admins and some don't want to enable this feature.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: `...and some don't want to enable this feature.` It's not like having it there causes them any harm or changes how they do things. It might actually end up being something that saves their bacon down the road.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it isn't possible.  Enabling the optional feature is a setting that is changed in the Configuration partition, which is forest-wide.

Setting:

```
CN=Recycle Bin Feature,CN=Optional Features,CN=Directory Service,CN=Windows NT,CN=Services,CN=Configuration,DC=contoso,DC=com
```

A good article on all the various details is here:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/askds/archive/2009/08/27/the-ad-recycle-bin-understanding-implementing-best-practices-and-troubleshooting.aspx